# HTTP POST request: From cURL command to GeoEvent Input Service

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

I am obviously lacking some skills with the HTTP requests, yet I have to implement it into GeoEventServer (GES). The request with cURL is pretty simple, and does not require authentication:

```
curl -X POST https://<api-url>/search -d {} -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'
```

It works fine in a command, and outputs a JSON string.

However, no output is created in GES: [image: Screenshot GES Service]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found a solution. With a configuration like this, it seems to work:

[image: Solution]

Apparently an empty payload has to be send, and the accepted MIME types need to be defined. No other changes were made.